# Using icons instead of PNG in Xamarin Forms Tabs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I use icons e.g. Material Icons instead of PNG iamges in my tabs in a Xamarin Forms app with Shell?

The following is how I defined tabs for home screen in my Xamarin Forms app:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Home">
   <FlyoutItem.Icon>
      <FontImageSource
         FontFamily="MISHRP"
         Glyph="{StaticResource HomeIcon}"
         Color="White" />
   </FlyoutItem.Icon>
   <Tab Title="Dashboard" Icon="icon_dashboard.png">
      <ShellContent Route="Dashboard" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Dashboard}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="My Feed" Icon="{StaticResource Feed}">
      <ShellContent Route="MyFeed" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MyFeed}"/>
   </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

As you can see in above code, in the first tab item (Dashboard), I use a PNG image and that displays fine in my app.

In the second TAB item (My Feed), I tried using an icon I defined in my `App.xaml` page but that doesn't show at all.

How do I use icons in tabs in a Shell Xamarin Forms app?

Comment: Like this , My Coffee App from James Montemagno https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MyCoffeeApp/blob/master/MyCoffeeApp/MyCoffeeApp/AppShell.xaml

Comment: Sam, show the line(s) in App.xaml that declare `Feed` resource. Compare that to lines 111-115 from Bas' link.

Comment: @BasH If you post your response as an answer, I'll accept it so that you get credit. I already upvoted your comment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you use something like this , from the MyCoffeeApp

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MyCoffeeApp/blob/master/MyCoffeeApp/MyCoffeeApp/AppShell.xaml

```
  <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FAS"
                         Color="{AppThemeBinding 
                                Dark=White, 
                                Light={StaticResource SystemGray5Dark}}"
                         Glyph="{StaticResource IconCoffee}"/>
        </Tab.Icon>
```